# 302 Okta redirect - CORS issue

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, cors, openid-connect, okta

I have a spring boot application configured to use Okta as SP initiated SSO, I have configured Okta developer account to use "OIDC - OpenID Connect" and "Web Application" as application type.
[image]

I have no issues reaching Okta's login page when I access a SP endpoint from a browser Ex: http://localhost:8080/api/login

However when I call the API end point from my React application it fails with CORS issue

```
axios({
    method: 'GET',
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/login',
    withCredentials: true
})
.then(response => {
    if (response.data.userID)
    {
        console.log("UserId:" + response.data.userID);
    }
})
.catch(error => {
    console.error(error);
})
```

Here is the header information where the re-direct to Okta(302) seems the problem:
[image]

I have updated the react app's url trusted origins in Okta admin console

[image]

Following are the Okta's Sign-in redirect uris

[Okta Signin URIs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QT6Ej.png)

Here is my spring boot Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("authorization", "content-type", "x-auth-token"));
        configuration.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("x-auth-token"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity webSecurity) throws Exception {
        webSecurity
                .ignoring()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.OPTIONS, "/**")
                .and()
                .ignoring();
    }
    
}
```

Any idea? what am I missing here?

Comment: I don't see any issues with CORS here, at least from what you described. Your web-app redirects your call to `/api/login` to `/login`. Not sure why, but it's not clear from the description above if Okta is involved here. My feeling is that your frontend doesn't have any session info with your backend, hence backend does redirection to `/login`

Comment: /login is the Okta's sigin URI, i have updated the question. If it redirects i should get Okta's login page instead i get CORS issue.

Comment: are you sure you are getting CORS issue from Okta and not from your back end? I don't see anywhere in the info you provided a single call to Okta URL

Comment: http://localhost:8080/login is configured as Re-Direct URI in Okta's admin console, If you observe the response header it is trying to re-direct to the /login uri, i have posted the Okat's admin console Sigin URIs

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong flow for used technology. It is mentioned also in the app type:
[image]

Use correct flow - `Authorization Code Flow with Proof Key for Code Exchange (PKCE)` in your case for React app (Native Application) and you won't have CORS issue. Or write your frontend as server side application and not SPA (React).